# Android Studio: SavedInstanceState of object doesn't work

Tags: java, android, serialization, onsaveinstancestate

I have a self made object called "MemoryCard", which has implemented **View.OnClickListener** and **Serializable** and is extended to **Activity**.

I declared `MemoryCard card;` as a data field outside my onCreate() method and
my **onSaveInstanceState** methode looks like this:

```
   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("CARD", card);
    }
```

And inside my **OnCreate** stands

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        card = new MemoryCard(this, 0, 1, R.drawable.testImage); // given parameters
    }
    else {
        card = (MemoryCard) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("CARD");
    }
```

But I always get exceptions that my App stops. Did I something wrong or MemoryCard mustn't have anything extended or implemented?

Comment: Post logcat please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put before super method call

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("CARD", card);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }
```